# Problem understanding JSON Array request?

Tags: java, android, json

I am learning to work with JSON requests, but I have problem with parameters in this request. I know the first on is the the post of the request, second one is the URL address and the last one is the Response, but what is this "null" for? I have copied this from Google developer page for Volley and changed the JsonObjectRequest to Array Request:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
    (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
```

Just another question, I believe that I have implemented Volley correctly in my android project but some have android studio couldn't find JsonArrayRequest Class but only Object Request. Why this happened? I copied a piece of code from somewhere else until android studio prompt me to import ArrayRequest.

Comment: Since it's a get request So it's a null otherwise incase of POST request there would be a json data body in place of "null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function declaration for `JsonObjectRequest` is

```
public JsonObjectRequest(int method,
                         String url,
                         JSONObject jsonRequest,
                         Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                         Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
```

and as mentioned in the [docs](https://afzaln.com/volley/index.html?com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.html)

> jsonRequest - A JSONObject to post with the request. Null is allowed and indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.

And in your case, since its a `GET` request it's null and for  `POST` request, the expected headers are passed to the API as a `JSONObject` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You writtened 4th parameter is wrong  try this piece of code

```
       JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET,
                    Url,
                    null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            // Do
```

Comment: I want to know what is parameter 'null' stands for here?

Comment: you can pass jsonarray data type parameter if you had data means